# Python: Create seperate dataframe from a dataframe with one category of the category variable column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below having 3 types of status -'complete','start' and 'fail'. I want to create another dataframe from this keeping only the "fail" status entries with their corresponding level number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this:

```
fail_df = df[df['status']=='fail']
```

or this with `str.contains`:

```
fail_df = df[df['status'].str.contains(r'fail',case=False)]
```

Both ways will give a new `dataframe` with only status being 'fail'. However, the `str.contains` method is more robust to typo's.